# Php, depencency injection: passing the whole container or the objects?

Tags: php

version A:

```
class A
{
    private $b, $c, $d, $e;

    public function __constructor (B $b, C $c, D $d, E $e)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->c = $c
.
.
.

    }
}

class B
{
}

class C
{
}

class D
{
}
```

I heard many times that application should not be aware of DI container itself. Well, then this is the clearest sollution, but requires tons of codes which is unrelated to class A itself, and has to be modified whenever another object is must be reached.
Version 2:

```
class Container
{
    public function getB()
    {
        return new B();
    }

    public function getC()
    {
        return new C();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

    class A
    {
        private $container;

        public function __constructor(Container $container)
        {
            $this->container = $container;
        }
    }
```

this is shorter but this time Container it tightly coupled. Plus, if there are 10000 objects in Container, Im not sure its a good approact to reach them all...

which way to go?

Comment: Inject only the dependencies you need. If your class requires way too many dependencies then you should question your design choices.

Comment: imo, A DIC (dependency Injection Container) should have 'one headful of stuff in it'. i.e. 'S.O.L.I.D' principles apply to DIC's as well as other parts of the system. It may be you have one DIC per sub-system...  Also, have you considered using `factories` to create your objects? The Factory knows about the DIC but the objects have no idea how they came into existence? They just know that they have everything they need to complete the task?